# How to find top 20 most frequent words in arraylist

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, hashmap

I have a task where I was given a file with text. That text is part of a book. My task is to transfer that file into arraylist, hashmap (one of those) which I did. The second part of the job is to find 20 most frequent words from that file and sort them in descending order.

So far I inserted all those words from file into hashmap and into arraylist (the code is provided below), I did both those things in separate methods. hashmap method is returning only numbers, while arraylist is returning only most frequent word, with number of repetitions.

So 1st part of code is going to be hashmap

```
public void findWords() throws Exception {
    // ovde traxim 20 reci koje se najcesce ponavljaju u tekstu
    String line;
    Integer counter = 0;
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("src/Fajl/blab");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String string[] = line.toLowerCase().split("([,.\\s]+)");
        for (String s : string) {
            if (hashmap.containsKey(s)) {
                counter++;
            } else
                counter = 1;
            hashmap.put(s, counter);
        }
    }
```

The next part is sorting by value, and displaying number of repetition of top 20 words, from most to least

```
Collection<Integer> values = mapaKnjiga.values();
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(values);
    Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder());
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
}
```

Comment: hello, can you add your code ?

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: please provide the code to see what you've done so far

Comment: Sorry, had to switch from win to linux, code is soon here

Comment: what you need is sorting the map by values in descending order. Do check this for example https://howtodoinjava.com/sort/java-sort-map-by-values/

Comment: You want top 20 words or frequency?

Comment: @chaitanya89 both

Comment: @TavernaJoe I've updated my answer as per your requirement, please check if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Consider words as your hashmap with words as key and count as values.

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> reverseSortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

words.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
                .forEachOrdered(x -> reverseSortedMap.put(x.getKey(), x.getValue()));

List<String> finalList = reverseSortedMap.entrySet()
                                        .stream()
                                        .map(entry -> entry.getKey())
                                        .limit(20)
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a class TextCounter and add it to a list based on the data collected by the map

```
class TextCounter{
  String text;
  int count;
}
```

and now sort by his count value

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you want list of top 20 words and it's frequency in a map, reading words from a file, a java-8 solution would be

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Long> top20WordsByFrequency = null;
    try {
        // Convert a file into stream of lines
        top20WordsByFrequency = Files.lines(Paths.get("src/Fajl/blab"))
                // convert lines into words
                .flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line.toLowerCase().split("([,.\\\\s]+)")))
                // make a map by grouping by key as word and value as the count of the word
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())).entrySet().stream()
                // sort the map based on values (frequency) in reverse order and limit the map
                // to 20
                .sorted(Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder())).limit(20)
                // after limiting sort based on keys in descending order
                .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Long>comparingByKey().reversed())
                // preserve the order in a LinkedHashMap
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, (u, v) -> u, LinkedHashMap::new));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(top20WordsByFrequency);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using the stream API:

```
String[] words = {"one", "two", "two", "three", "three", "three"};
Map<String, Long> result = 
        Arrays.stream(words)
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                       Collectors.counting()));
```

And the second part:

```
List<Long> collect = result.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
                .limit(20)
                .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(collect);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your findWords() function is working correctly, where you have all the words and their count, you can follow next:

Since you have to print the count of a particular word. So you can start by defining a class Word with property content and count, and defining a default comparator.Something like this:

```
class Item implements Comparable<Item>{
   String word;
   int count;

public Item(String word, int count){
    this.count = count;
    this.word = word;
}

public int compareTo(Item word){
    //sorting in descending order
    return word.count - this.count;
}

public String toString(){
    return "Word: " + word +"Count: " + count;
}}
```

Define an ArrayList of items to hold the Item object:

```
ArrayList<Item> al = new ArrayList<>();
```

You can iterate all over the hashmap and then inserting each pair as :

```
Item item = new Item(word, count);
al.add(item);
```

And finally you can sort the list and then pick top 20 words:

```
Collections.sort(al);
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you all for your effort, and will to help.
I am beginner in Java programming and at the moment I am working on my final project for course.
I found the solution, which in my opinion is very, very hard to understand if you are on this lvl. This is not my solution, but it works.
First I populated hashmap with values from file, than I checked if that word already exists in file, if true counter++, if false counter =1. After that

```
public void dvadesetNajviseKoriscenih() throws Exception{
    // this is where I populate hashmap with values
    String line;
    Integer counter = 0;
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("src/Fajl/knjiga");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String string[] = line.toLowerCase().split(" ");
        for (String s : string) {
            // this is where I check if the word already exists
            if (hashmapName.containsKey(s)) {
                counter++; //however this counter here is not right, so I will have to change it.
            } else
                counter = 1;
            hashmapName.put(s, counter);
        }
    } //this below is where it sorts words by number of how many times it repeats...

    Map<String, Integer> sorted = hashmapName.entrySet().stream().sorted(comparingByValue())
            .collect(toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue(), (e1, e2) -> e2, LinkedHashMap::new));
    sorted = hashmapName.entrySet().stream().sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()))
            .limit(20).collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e2, LinkedHashMap::new));
    for (String s : sorted.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(s + " " + sorted.get(s));
    }
}
```

If someone knows what is happening in bottom part of the code, please fell free to explain to us, noobs :)
And of course, rate my solution :)
If anyone wants to practice on this task, feel free to write me on github/BojanBosnjak